# Replace Angular 16 polyfill

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli, polyfills

I am attempting to get a simple Angular 16 project created with the angular-cli to run in [sciter](https://sciter.com/)--which uses QuickJS. I have currently identified two changes that need to be made to the generated Angular `polyfill.js`--it seems these changes cannot live outside this file.

I have found that commenting out the "polyfills" key within `angular.json` prevents the creation of the `dist/polyfill.js`. I then imported my `polyfills.js` within `main.ts`. The problem now is Chrome complains about:

> main.ts:8 Error: NG0908: In this configuration Angular requires Zone.js

I have confirmed my polyfill file is the same as the generated version. I also tried variations of using the `scripts` section of the `angular.json` as well as importing inside the `index.html` header section. Nothing seems to work.

I have found that if I use this same approach with an Angular 16 project that does not contain any router code it seems to work just fine. For some reason the addition of the router code inside my project is causing problems.

What could I be missing? Any advice would be much appreciated.